# Abelian category with all direct limits but without all colimits

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903343/a-category-which-direct-limits-but-no-general-colimits) on the topic, I'd like to know if there is an abelian category that has all direct limits (or inverse limits, if dualising helps), but no  general colimits (limits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abelian category has all colimits if and only if it has all filtered colimits ("direct limit" is very confusing terminology and IMO should be avoided, because they *aren't limits*). This is because

- an abelian category has finite coproducts and coequalizers,
- arbitrary colimits can be expressed in terms of arbitrary coproducts and coequalizers, and
- arbitrary coproducts are filtered colimits of finite coproducts.

Comment: Well, math is full of bad conventions (I'll get you, function application from the left!), *direct limit* certainly is one of, but, alas, they won't go away. But thanks for the answer!